# Why is the regex pattern not matching in django 1.11?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to pass the ID as an argument to another page on the website using regex using django framework version 1.11:

```html
<h2><li><a href="{{school.id}}/">{{ school.name }}</a></li></h2>
```

urls.py

```py
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

app_name = "basic_app"

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^schools_list/$', views.SchoolList.as_view(), name='list'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.SchoolDetail.as_view(),name='detail'),
]
```

However I am getting a 404 Page not found after running the local server:
**^basic_app/ ^(?P\d+)/$ [name='detail']
The current path, basic_app/schools_list/1/, didn't match any of these.**

Comment: Did you mean to write `<a href="{% url 'detail' school.id %}">...</a>`?

Comment: When you write a relative url without a leading slash it means that your url begins from the current folder / directory. So when your url is `1/` with current url being `basic_app/schools_list/` your url is assumed to be `basic_app/schools_list/1/` causing an error as you have no such pattern. As The comment above points out you should write urls using the `url` template tag.

Comment: @yvesonline no I intended that. It does not work even if I remove it.

Comment: As @AbdulAzizBarkat points out correctly the problem stems from you supplying a relative url and this being interpreted as `basic_app/schools_list/1/`. So either prefix your `href` or use the `url` tag. I don't see any value gain composing a url manually so would recommend using the `url` tag.

Comment: @yvesonline can you share the exact code or related example using the method that you are suggesting?

Comment: For your example? Do: `<h2><li><a href="{% url 'detail' school.id %}">{{ school.name }}</a></li></h2>`

Comment: the above, solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<h2><li><a href="{% url 'basic_app:detail' school.id %}">{{ school.name }}</a></li></h2>
```

Use url tagging